# Where does MathJax store the id of the current equation being processed?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm currently trying to modify MathJax so that it outputs both to the original math element and a secondary element. The two elements have corresponding ids (e.g., if the math element is math001, the secondary element is text001), so all I would need to output to the secondary element is the the id of the first. I would like to output to the secondary element when the processInput function, but I can't figure out where the original id is stored (or if it's even passed to that function at all). In the documentation, I saw that the id is stored in the inputID property of instances of the ElementJax, but I can't seem to find a way to capture it during processing.

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [MathJax user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mathjax-users), where you are more likely to get an answer.  I'd suggest you describe more fully what you are trying to do, as I suspect there may be easier ways to do it, but you have not given enough information to really be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavideCervone. It looks like you were the one to answer my question in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/v2A04i5oiX0) as well.

Comment: Correct.  Having a more complete statement of what you were trying to do was a big help there.

Comment: breakpoint at `processInput: function (state) {` of `MathJax.js`,
but only after MathJax has already processed at least one equation (so it is already configured/initied), otherwise you will understand nothing